# Visual Studio Extensibility: Custom tracing 'source' in output

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

In a VS package, how do I create a separate entry in this `Output` drop down for my trace messages?

[image: Show output from: Build, Debug, etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions are written [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb168598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the remarks section. You `QueryService(typeof(SVsOutputWindow))` which gives you the `IVsOutputWindow` interface you can use to interact with it.

You can create panes dynamically or pre-register them. If you want to pre-register them, you can stick some keys in the registry to register one. Assuming you're deploying as a .vsix extension, you can either add those keys to a .pkgdef manually, or use something like VisualGit's [ProvideOutputWindowAttribute](https://github.com/pvginkel/VisualGit/blob/master/VisualGit.Package/Attributes/ProvideOutputWindow.cs) which implements a ProvideOutputWindowAttribute that you would simply put on your Package class along with the rest of your Provide* attributes.

Comment: Thanks, one addition is that I also found `Package.GetOutputPane` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.getoutputpane.aspx)) method which calls `IVsOutputWindow` and creates pane automatically if it did not exist.